# Prolog : C-style constant OR alias?

Tags: prolog, constants, alias

Is there a way to define/declare constants/alias in Prolog.

I have a atom that i use often. I want to declare it once and later if I decide to change it to do it in one single place.

```
def BLAH = blah
.....
clause(BLAH(abc,de), true) 
... and so on ...
```

Comment: Technically, you could do them just like in C, then run the C pre-processor. In your example, use `#define BLAH blah` then run `cpp -P my_file.pl`. But Prolog doesn't support this sort of thing natively.

Comment: WHY you need it?  Atom isn't just a string but is the index in the symbol-table. Why do you prefer BLAH over blah? the first btw has variable syntax, did you mean HiLog?

Comment: Pretty much nothing in Prolog is mutable except for Variables? If you use abc as an atom in one statement, it will still be the same atom abc in another statement. `'abc' == abc, abc == abc.` Think of it as a string pool that is used for your entire KB. For regular integers, well they are evaluated as binary so 101 will always equal 101.

Answer (score 0):

The Prolog equivalent of a constant is defined by a unary predicate with a single fact. For example:

```
my_atom(blah).
```

This can then be used in any number of places:

```
important_body(Body) :-
    my_atom(Atom),
    Head =.. [Atom,abc,de],
    clause(Head, Body).

write_my_atom :-
    my_atom(Atom),
    write(Atom).
```

Then, to change the value of the "constant" that gets bound to `Atom` in the above predicates, you only need to change the `my_atom/1` fact.